# Lodash: how to split the array of objects using some separator object

Tags: arrays, split, lodash

Considering I'm having the array:

```
var arr = [
   {type:'a', name:'a1'}, {type:'b', name:'b1'}, {type:'hr'}, 
   {type:'a', name:'a2'}, {type:'b', name:'b2'}, {type:'hr'}, 
   {type:'a', name:'a3'}, {type:'b', name:'b2'}, {type:'hr'} 
]
```

I'd split it into array of arrays of objects using `{type:'hr'}` object as separator element. So the result is:

```
[
[{type:'a', name:'a1'}, {type:'b', name:'b1'}],
[{type:'a', name:'a3'}, {type:'b', name:'b2'}],
[{type:'a', name:'a3'}, {type:'b', name:'b3'}]
]
```

Think `lodash` is useful for it?

Currently I've used `_.map` for this:

```
 var result = [], sub = [];                                                                                                                                    _.map(tokens, (it, idx) => {                                                                                                                                      if(it.type === 'hr'){                                                     
        result.push(sub);                                                 
                sub = [];                                                 
            } else {                                                      
                sub.push(it);                                             
            }                                                             
        });                                                               
        if(sub.length){                                                   
            result.push(sub);                                             
        }                                                                 
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand - you want a split that works similar to splitting a string, only with arrays. For example, with a string if you have `"aaxbbxcc"` and you split on `x`, you'll get `["aa", "bb", "cc"]` whereas for your use case given an array like `[ "a", "a", "x", "b", "b", "x", "c", "c"]` and splitting on `"x"` should produce `[ ["a", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["c", "c"] ]`. Is that correct?

Comment: yep, you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#reduce) and create a new sub-array when you find `{type:'hr'}`:

```js
var arr = [
   {type:'a', name:'a1'}, {type:'b', name:'b1'}, {type:'hr'}, 
   {type:'a', name:'a2'}, {type:'b', name:'b2'}, {type:'hr'}, 
   {type:'a', name:'a3'}, {type:'b', name:'b2'}, {type:'hr'} 
];
var delimiter = { type: 'hr' };
var res = _.reduce(arr, function(result, obj, index) {
  if (_.isEqual(obj, delimiter)) {
    if (index !== arr.length - 1) result.push([]);
  } else {
    _.last(result).push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}, [[]]);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the solution. I was about to post the same, but you were faster :P The only "problem" is that this will add an extra empty array, whereas OP's expected output doesn't have it. If indeed there shouldn't be empty arrays there, a simple `filter` will take care of that. However, that would be a separate thing operation - as far as I'm concerned, empty arrays in the results are correct - this is also how the string `split` operates adding empty strings if there is nothing to put in the delimiters.

Comment: @Vld Thanks. You're right. Added an extra condition to get rid of the last empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```js
function splitBy(array, predicate, result = []) {
  const taken = _.takeWhile(array, predicate);
  const remaining = _.tail(_.dropWhile(array, predicate));

  return remaining.length ?
    splitBy(remaining, predicate, result.concat([taken])) :
    result.concat([taken]);
}

splitBy(
  arr,
  _.negate(_.partial(_.isEqual, { type: 'hr' })))
);
```

The idea is to use [takeWhile()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#takeWhile) to get the items that don't match the separator. Then, [dropWhile()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#dropWhile) creates the next chunk of array to iterate over by passing it to `splitBy()`.

The actual predicate that's used to determine what the separator is is passed in as an argument, meaning that you can reuse this function for other kinds of separators.